# Any way to get entire web page from SDK by API call?

Tags: android, html, api, sdk, liferay

I Have one SDK (android). Is there any way to get entire webpage (HTML javascript whole page) by making API call?

There are many ways to get URL of webpage. I dont want URL I want full HTML of webpage directly so that I can use that in mobile app.

Is it possible? If it is then how? and If it is not then why not?

Any type of help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the URL of the page, the API is called HTTP GET and you only request the page with that URL - that will give you all the HTML that is on the page, including all the embedding tags that refer to external javascript, css, images etc.

Comment: Thnx. Is there any way to get HTML directly without getting URL and then call HTTP GET?

Comment: If you don't have the URL - how do you describe which page you'd like to get?

Comment: yah but except URL can we directly get full HTML of that page in response? Is it possible? I mean to ask can we get directly HTML of page in response of API call\?

Comment: @ssg if that was meant to answer my question "how do you describe which page you'd like to get?" I don't get it... How - if not through the URL - do you denote the page that you're interested in?

Comment: Its not the answer of your question. Im asking possibility of my question that should I get direct HTML not URL from API? API call is giving me URL in response but I want HTML of that URL in response.

Comment: What's keeping you from issueing a GET request with that URL that you now obviously have? I stand by my answer: Take that URL, issue a GET request to it and receive the content. Heck, you don't even let us know of the actual API that you're getting the URL with - so we have no idea what data you have available. Plus, I don't understand why it's desirable to immediately get HTML content on yet another way than through HTTP. An API is *meant* to deliver data. HTTP GET is *meant* to deliver content.